# SPDY "Hello server" with Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, spdy

I'm trying to setup a minimal HTTP over SPDY server with [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/), for testing purposes.  I'm working on this code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.http.HTTPSPDYServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler;

public class MySPDYHelloServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();

        SslContextFactory sslFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslFactory.setKeyStorePath("dummy_keystore.jks");
        sslFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");
        sslFactory.setProtocol("TLSv1");

        Connector connector = new HTTPSPDYServerConnector(sslFactory);
        connector.setPort(8443);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        server.setHandler( new AbstractHandler(){
            public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest,
                    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                    throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                baseRequest.setHandled(true);
                response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
            }
        } );

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

I've generated the keystore with:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore dummy_keystore.jks
```

When I point Google Chrome (SPDY enabled) to `https://localhost:8443` it warns me about the untrusted certificate then loads *forever*.

The pure SPDY client-server examples (from [here](http://www.smartjava.org/content/how-use-spdy-jetty)) work and a simple HTTPS server work too; the issue seems related to the [HTTPSPDYServerConnector](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-7/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/spdy/http/HTTPSPDYServerConnector.html) class.

Here's the list of the JARs that I'm using:

```
jetty-all-7.6.7.v20120910.jar
npn-boot-7.6.2.v20120308.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
spdy-core-7.6.7.v20120910.jar
spdy-jetty-7.6.7.v20120910.jar
spdy-jetty-http-7.6.7.v20120910.jar
```

And for what concerns my Java environment:

```
$ cat /opt/jdk1.7.0_07/release 
JAVA_VERSION="1.7.0"
OS_NAME="Linux"
OS_VERSION="2.6"
OS_ARCH="i586"
```

## Solution addendum

[jesse mcconnell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1185262/jesse-mcconnell) provided the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12689770/477168), anyway those who use Eclipse may find the following useful.

The JAR `npn-boot-7.6.2.v20120308.jar` must (also) be placed in:

```
Run Configurations... -> Classpath -> Bootstrap Entries -> Add External JARs
```

Note that since **order matters**, that entry must appear **before** the `JRE System Library`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the npn-boot as a bootclasspath jar when starting this up?

Stock jvm will not support npn (next protocol negotiation) and spdy will not work, so you have to make sure that the npn-boot jar is being used in conjunction with -Xbootclasspath option.  The kinda sounds like your issue since your dealing with certificate loading and then its stalling...also that you refer to npn-boot as a dependency when it is more of a replacement of jvm classes then a typical dependency.

Comment: Oh, I just thrown all the JARs in the Eclipse's class path... many thanks!